# How to load resources when using cocoapods resource_bundles and testing in a different bundle

Tags: testing, core-data, cocoapods

im using cocoapods for managing a private library im working on. Currently i have a subspec with all my models, including the .xcdatamodel file for core data modeling. My podspec file looks like this.

```
  s.subspec 'Data' do |ds|
            ...
            ds.resource_bundle   = { :DataKit => '/Data/Schema/App.xcdatamodeld' }
            ...
        end
```

When i need to access my .xcdatamodel y look up for my DataKit bundle.

For example

```
    NSURL *url                               = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/DataKit.bundle",[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]]];
    NSBundle *dataBundle                     = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:url];
    NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:@[dataBundle]];
```

The problem i'm having is the i need to test some code in the Data subspec, so, when i run the tests there is no DataKit bundle. I wouldn't like to add conditional code for loading the bundle depending if im testing or not. Any good solution for this?

Comment: It is unclear why the data is not there for testing - or if that is your intent.  If it is your intent, can't you just have a dependency on that subspec for testing?  I must be missing something.  If you don't want the actual data, you can test  transform / processing code as you would a viewmodel - with fake / mock data source objects.